# how Compaction works in Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, tombstone

My input is `1:45$` and we are processing the message and next I am updating the `1:null`.

I do see still  the `1:45$` in the topic along with the `1:null` (I can see both the messages)

I want output to be `1:null` in the same topic.

I have used this code:

```
kafka-topics --create --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --topic latest-       product-price --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --config "cleanup.policy=compact" --config "delete.retention.ms=100"  --config "segment.ms=100" --config "min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.01"



kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic latest-    product-price --property parse.key=true --property key.separator=::

1::45$
1::null


kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic latest-product-price --property  print.key=true --property key.separator=:: --from-beginning
```

But I do not find any compaction in my case and need some inputs to make the value as `1::null`

Comment: How many segments does this topic have? Log compaction does not account for the active segment.

Comment: Did you enable the log cleaner?

Comment: Is this one “log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio” ??

Answer (score 4):

Compaction in Kafka is not immediate.  If you send two messages with the same key to a compacted topic, and you have a live consumer on that topic, that consumer *will* see both messages come through.

Periodically, there's a background cleaner thread that goes looking for duplicate keys in compacted topics, and removes the overwritten records, so that a consumer that pulls down the data *after* that log cleaner has run, will only see the last change/update for a particular key.  So, topic compaction seems to be better suited for consumers that run periodically, not ones that are active 100% of the time.

One thing that you can tune how often this background log cleaner thread runs, to maybe run those consumers more often. Look for the `log.cleaner` configuration parameters in the Kafka documentation:  https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs

There's a good explanation on how Kafka log compaction works at this link:
https://medium.com/swlh/introduction-to-topic-log-compaction-in-apache-kafka-3e4d4afd2262